# Can I keep using DLC on a borrowed Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, fallout-new-vegas, drm

I pre-ordered *Fallout: New Vegas* from GameStop and got the Classic Pack DLC as a "reward." I own a 360 Arcade and don't have an Xbox Live account. My girlfriend owns a 360 Elite and has a silver Live account.

Since I don't have Live, my girlfriend downloaded the Classic Pack to the Arcade. I started two games with Classic Pack items and they worked fine for a while. As far as I know, anyone can use DLC on the machine it's downloaded to first (in this case, the Arcade); only the downloader can use it on other machines (in this case, the Elite). Unfortunately, the Arcade red-ringed today; more specifically, it gave me the E74 error. (Details: go to the [Xbox support website](http://support.xbox.com/en-us/pages/xbox-360/troubleshoot/hardware/flashing-lights-wizard.aspx), click "one flashing light" and "error code E74.")

I figured, okay, no problem, I'll send the Arcade in for service — it's still covered by the [E74 extended warranty](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969905) — and use the Elite for now. But when I tried to load the game, I saw

> "Some of your downloadable content is corrupt and could not be loaded."

And that's the story of how I found out that licenses are tied to specific consoles, not just Live accounts or hard drives. (Ref: [Microsoft license transfer FAQ](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Support/LicenseMigration/FAQ))

Now, I could just load my game and go, but I'm afraid of losing my items permanently because of [the last issue I had](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8054/how-can-i-reliably-play-fallout-3-dlc-without-an-internet-connection). I could also use up the annual license transfer to move everything to the Elite, but that could have unintended consequences for other savegames; if not mine, then my girlfriend's. I'm also not even sure that will work; would the Elite become the new "first" machine, where anyone can use DLC? Or would there be no more "first" machine?

In short: is there anything I can do to play *F:NV* for the next three weeks that doesn't involve losing my Classic Pack items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here are the rules for DLC:

- **Anyone** can play DLC on the Console on which it was purchased
- The person **who purchased the DLC** can play it on **any** console

Now it seems like you already knew this part.  However, there is a third rule!

- Once per year you can move all your DLC to **a new xbox**!  It is now considered to have been purchased on that xbox.

Using this magical third rule you (or your girlfriend) can recall all your DLC to a new box and anyone can play it on that box.  It would become the "First" xbox in your example.  This should not affect any saves on that box.

Comment: thanks! I didn't mention the third rule, but I did see it on the license transfer FAQ I linked. But as you say, it's only a once-a-year deal. The problem is that I don't want to be stuck using the Elite in three weeks when the repaired Arcade comes back from MS. Would this fall under the repair exemption? (Third item in [this FAQ](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Support/LicenseMigration/FAQ)) +1 for your second-to-last sentence alone, though.

Comment: @Torgamus possibly, you'd have to phone MS to be sure. You can, however, always re-download to the arcade if only your account is going to use it on that system

Comment: just for closure purposes: called Microsoft and got a long answer from the support guy. I asked him if his answer boiled down to "yes, but not really" and he said it did. So, no real answer there.

Comment: :( @Torgamus.  I just reread your answer, and you said you don't have an account?  Are you aware that a Silver, Xbox Live account is Free? That you can use said free account for purchasing DLC and the like?