# Other users being able to access DLC that I've purchased using Microsoft Points

Tags: xbox-network

If I buy Microsoft Points and buy a map pack, can other users of my xbox use them? I suppose the question is, who can access downloaded  purchased content on a console, is it only on the ID that purchased the points, or is it all users on the console. Any guidance greatly appreciated.
I want to buy MS Points with my Live ID, but my son wants to pick the content to download to be used under his id. What's the best way? I buy online, or he buys from a shop?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the first half of your question:  as mentioned in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9748/can-i-keep-using-dlc-on-a-borrowed-xbox-360/9749#9749), **anyone** can play DLC on the console on which you purchased it.  (Because it is also linked to your XBL account, you can also play it on any console.)

I know there is some way to set up some kind of "family" setup so you can control what your children buy and play, but I don't know any details on that.  Hopefully someone else can fill in those blanks.